# NIC light is turned off after boot on Redhat 4.6 server

Tags: linux, redhat

I have a 2950 blade server setup with Red Hat 4.6 installed. I cannot get the NIC to work properly after reinstalling Linux. I activated the NIC, but the NIC light will not turn on when I plug the network cable into the hub. The status light on the hub will not turn on either. If I run ifconfig, the NIC status is UP. Also I can ping the IP address that I assign to the Linux machine, but I can't ping anything else that is plugged into the hub. When I reboot the system, the NIC light will stay on until the system fully boots and then it will turn off again. Is there something else that I need to do to get the NIC working? It appears to be disabled even though ifconfig says that it is UP. Maybe I need to configure something within the blade server (iDRAC)?

Comment: are you connected to a cisco switch?

Comment: The server is connected to a Hawking Technology 10/100 16-Port Switch (HFS16T).

Comment: I installed Red Hat Enterprise 5.3 and I do not experience the NIC problem that I get with 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plugging the cable into the other NIC on the 2950? The order in which the kernel discovers the NICs on most Dell servers changed at some point - can't remember exactly which version of the kernel.

Comment: Between 4 and 5 on redhat systems the detect order seems to have changed.